# Keyboard repeat stop working on Virtual PC

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine

I am running Virtual PC 2007 (6.0) on a Windows XP host. My virtual boxes are all Windows Server 2003. Every so often, key repeat stops working.

Normally in Windows if you hold down any key (<kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, etc.) for half a second, the key starts repeating. In *all* of my virtual boxes, key repeat doesn’t work.

Restarting a single virtual instance doesn’t help. The only thing that seems to work is rebooting the host, which is a real pain as I am running Domain Controllers, etc. on all the virtual boxes.

Is there a fix out there for this? Google was not my friend on this issue.

UPDATE: Still having this problem about once a month, I did discover that I could save state on each instance and reboot the host, the functionality returns and it is faster than shutting down each virtual instance and rebooting the host.

Comment: Have you set the keyboard repeat in each of the guest OSes?

Comment: Keyboard repeat hasn't changed in any of the boxes. It just stops working. Even virtual boxes I don't use (like the DC) it stops working. I rebooted over the weekend and it works again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally figured out the problem: The Shift key on my keyboard was locking at random times, which caused the issue. Replacing the keyboard corrected the problem.